# How do I append a list of data to multiple new columns in a CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

```
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        sorter(filename, all_users)
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='windows-1252') as read_obj, \
            open(f'../{sensor}/{sensor}-{count}.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:
        count += 1
        csv_reader = reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in read_obj)
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        row = next(csv_reader)
        for data in userData:
            for row in csv_reader:
                row.append(data)
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

I have list with user data called userData, however when I try to append items in the list to columns in the CSV, it doesn't work and only writes the first item of data in the list. How do I append everything without deleting any of the original data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file you're writing to [in append mode.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
open(f'../{sensor}/{sensor}-{count}.csv', 'a', newline='') as write_obj:
   # do stuff
```